# Android Studio error - Inconvertible types, Cannot cast Fragment

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEIPV.png)Trying to make a simple program using fragments. the exact error I get is :

```
"Inconvertible types, Cannot cast android.app.Fragment to com.example.something.something.WorkoutDetailFragment"
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag); //ERROR!
         frag.setWorkoutid(1);
     }
```

}

(my activity_main_xml code)

Comment: Share your `activity_main.xml` as well. Where did you add that fragment to your activity?

Comment: yup, just added it

Answer (score 1):

Your WorkoutDetailFragment should extends android.app.Fragment, not android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Try it out~